# Find text from a file and set it as a variable in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I am trying to build a script that sends me updates and notifications from cex.io. Please keep on reading below, so I may guide you until the point I have trouble with.

The first simple script in this operation goes to cex.io's trading page for BTC/GHS. It records ands saves the text to a file every 4 seconds. It works great. It doesn't need to have safari refresh because the site pushes info to the browser live.

```
repeat
set the webpage_content to ""
tell application "Safari" to set the webpage_content to the text of document 1
set theText to webpage_content
set a to "Macintosh HD:Users:PRIVATE:Desktop:CEX:"
set theFile to (open for access file ((a) & "CEXRaw") with write permission)
write theText to theFile
close access theFile
delay 4
end repeat
```

### -

And it returns this in a main file every 4 seconds: (note I cut off a chunk from the bottom and the top of the file, because they are unimportant)

```
GHS:
0.05233439
BTC:
0.00000223
NMC:
0.00002939
LTC:
0.00000000
GHS/BTC
0.02362958 LTC/BTC
0.02438131 NMC/BTC
0.00597565 GHS/NMC
3.96951800 BF1/BTC
1.67000000 Fund Account
GHS/BTC
Last price:
0.02362958
Daily change:
-0.00018042
Today's open:
0.02381000
24h volume:
73812.35539255
```

### -

I now need an applescript to read that file, and return wanted values. But I'm lost on how to write it.

It needs to find the number under BTC, and set it as a variable.
It needs to find the number under GHS, and set it as a variable.
It needs to find the number under Last Price, and set it as a variable.

If anyone could script that really quick for me, or tell me how to do it, that would be amazing. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if those values will always be in the same paragraph counts, you could just pull them by line number.

```
set theCEXRaw to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:PRIVATE:Desktop:CEX:CEXRaw"
set theGHS to paragraph 2 of theCEXRaw
set theBTC to paragraph 4 of theCEXRaw
set thePRICE to paragraph 17 of theCEXRaw
```

You'd need to adjust the paragraph numbers. But, assuming that paragraph numbers aren't reliably consistent, in pure Applescript, you'd use Applescript's Text Item Delimiters.

```
set theCEXRaw to read file "Macintosh HD:Users:PRIVATE:Desktop:CEX:CEXRaw"
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {("GHS:
"), ("BTC:
"), ("Last price:
")}
set theCEXRaw to text items of theCEXRaw

set theGHS to paragraph 1 of item 2 of theCEXRaw
set theBTC to paragraph 1 of item 3 of theCEXRaw
set thePRICE to paragraph 1 of item 4 of theCEXRaw
```

Note that the three delims include a return character inside the quotes. You will want to capture the old delimiter first, so you can restore it, and hopefully you can do the setting of the delimiter outside your repeat loop to save juice.
You could also use do shell script with sed or grep to strip each value.

Answer (score 0):

You could get those values using `the offset` which searches a string for a substring and returns it's character position.

eg, `set pos to the offset of "world" in "hello world" -- returns 7`

Here is a solution that uses this principal to find your values and convert them into the Applescript floating point type `Number`

```
property line_delimiter : linefeed -- OR return OR return & linefeed pending your data

set results to "GHS:
0.05233439
BTC:
0.00000223
NMC:
0.00002939
LTC:
0.00000000
Last price:
0.02362958"

processCEX(results)

on processCEX(in_text)      
    set btc_val to searchNumberValueLine("BTC:" & line_delimiter, in_text)
    set ghs_val to searchNumberValueLine("GHS:" & line_delimiter, in_text)
    set last_price_val to searchNumberValueLine("Last price:" & line_delimiter, in_text)

    display dialog ("btc = " & btc_val & return & "ghs = " & ghs_val & return & " last price = " & last_price_val)
end processCEX

on searchNumberValueLine(key_name, input_str)

    set start_index to the offset of key_name in input_str

    if (start_index is not 0) then
        set input_str to text (start_index + ((length of key_name))) thru -1 of input_str
        set end_index to the offset of line_delimiter in input_str

        if (end_index is 0) then
            return input_str as number
        else
            return (text 1 thru (end_index - 1) of input_str) as number
        end if          
    else
        return -1
    end if
end searchNumberValueLine
```

Also i'd recommend against writing to a text file if you don't need to, to avoid any file io issues when reading the same file from a different script, given you are modifying it every 4 seconds.

You could change your code to something like this:

```
repeat
  set the webpage_content to ""
  tell application "Safari" to set the webpage_content to the text of document 1
  processCEX(webpage_content)
  delay 4
end repeat
```